# How do I find a laptop or desktop that supports external 4k monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, 4k-resolution

I have a Seiki 4k monitor, now looking for 4k content. Looking at a bunch of (lower-end) 4k laptops and desktops, how do I find out whether it 1) supports an external 4k monitor and/or 2) supports multiple external monitors?

I don't mind if one of the external monitors is sitting on VGA, but it turns out that some laptops don't allow VGA and HDMI to be used simultaneously (and if it's true, how do I find out?)

Answer (score 1):

Find the graphics card with the laptop, most likely will be integrated graphics that comes with your CPU. Then search to see if that supports 4k monitor. The intel i5-4xxx processors do, for example, as Intel Graphics 4000 seems to support 4k.

I think the best approach is to ensure you're getting a latest-generation CPU, find one or more machines that you're considering, check which CPU or graphics they have, and google whether those specific machines/CPU/graphics options support 4k. Some machines are reportedly a bit flakey, some you'll find someone who has got it working just fine.

Comment: My laptop has Intel i5-2540M and it does not support 4k out of the box, although maybe it's Seiki's fault? Hmm

Comment: Output from Speccy: Generic PnP Monitor (1366x768@60Hz)
SE50UY04-1 (1920x1080@59Hz)
Intel HD Graphics 3000 (Holco Enterprise Co,/Shuttle Computer)

Comment: Yeah sorry, I meant the latest i5, 4th gen. The HD Graphics 3000 shouldn't support 4k ... although I'm sure I've read some blog about a dude that got it working somehow.